# Magento rating (stars) on store level, taken from product level

Tags: extensions, store-view

We are looking to find a magento rating (stars) on store level. One that also would provide a block with the stars, etc.

There are some examples out there. I have seen one with only text.

For the extension experts:

- Is there an extension that supports ratings on a store level (stars)?
- Possibly offering a block to show it + support for rich snippets
- That would maybe take all product ratings, average it and show that as a total
- And if you click on the block you see a page with all reviews in a nicely formatted list. With links to the product where the review came from

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we ended up using this extension: http://www.magmodules.nl/magento-extensions/marketing/schema-org-rich-snippets.html

It generates snippets per PRODUCT and CATEGORY

Works fine. Only problem though is that it generates a new block under the product and category page (ith duplicate content) - instead of tagging the already available rating/descriptions that were already shown

(Not STORE level: question still open)